# Can't access the Google Compute VM by any port except 22

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have already set the firewall rules.
[firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG9Os.png)
And I also stop the firewall in VM.
[stop the firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJszw.png)
But I still can't access the VM by any port except 22.
[try to access the VM from another Linux host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3ZyA.png)
[port 22 success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AsGH.png)

Comment: Do you have software running that is listening on the other ports? Your question is not very clear on what you are trying to do and what you have configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use "network tags" for your GCP firewall rules and VM instances, this feature will allow you to assign firewall rule(s) to specific VM instance(s).

To guide you through this process, I will use the following scenario (please apply it to your scenario):

We need to create a firewall rule to allow ingress traffic by port 3306 from any part of the world (0.0.0.0/0) for an instance where mysql database service is installed, the problem is that you have 1000 VM instances and you only want to apply this rule to 1 instance.

1. You need to be sure that port is listening in your OS, for this you can use:

1.1 netstat -tulpn | grep 3306 
1.2 telnet localhost 3306 (may be you will need to install telnet package)

NOTE: If you can reach your port locally now you have to focus on firewall rules.

2. You have to add a "Network tag" in the instance you want to assign the firewall rule:

2.1 Go to the VM instances page.
2.2 Select the instance.
2.3 On the VM instance details page, click Edit.
2.4 In the "Network tags section" specify a name for the tag, for example: "mysql-public"
2.5 Click Save.

NOTE: For this procedure you can follow this guide: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_and_removing_tags

3. Go to firewall rule page.

3.1 Click Create firewall rule.
3.2  Enter a Name for the firewall rule. 
3.3 Specify the Network where the firewall rule will be implemented.
3.4 Specify the Priority of the rule. 
The lower the number, the higher the priority.
3.5 For the Direction of traffic, choose ingress or egress.
3.6 For the Action on match, choose allow or deny.
3.7 Specify the Targets of the rule. Choose "Specified target tags" from the drop-down menu.
In this step you also have to type the name (e.g. "mysql-public") of your "Network tag" in the Target tags field.
3.8 For an ingress rule, specify the Source filter.
3.9 For an egress rule, specify the Destination filter: 
3.10 Define the Protocols and ports to which the rule will apply.

NOTE: For this procedure you can follow this guide: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Try your connection, if you have further questions we can discuss about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to update sshd port on your Linux server.
2. Open port which you wanted to connect on VPC firewall rule.